# how to use multiple data validation in one column (A:A) in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

im want to use multiple data validatin in one column (A:A) of google sheet

in google sheet column (A:A) have a numeric value and im want to keep it unique when user enter duplicate value it show error and not allow to enter duplicate value and if user enter the dupliacte value its highlight the cell and am also want user just enter 15 digit only not less then 15 or not greater then 15.

Comment: Click right button on the column and click on data validation. Then you can add some rule for data validation.

Answer (score -1):

try this custom formula:

```
=ISNUMBER(A1)*(LEN(A1)=15)*(COUNTIF(A:A; A1)=1)
```